# Is the Northwind database still hosted somewhere

Tags: northwind

Various tutorials floating about the Microsoft Website require you to add the NorthWind database as a web reference, in particular the following link:

```
http://www.mcwtech.com/northwinddata/products.asmx
```

This doesn't seem to exist anymore so I am asking if this is mirrored anywhere else as I am following [a great tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa902693%28v=office.12%29.aspx), and to continue I need to add this web reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can download it here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23654

And here is another one:

http://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/71634

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server 2012 the installation process is quite different and the database is also different. I got the solution and it helps me. if you are using sql 2012 you can also follow.
[Northwind Database for Sql Server 2012](http://queryasp.net/download/northwind.zip)

Answer (score 0):

This is the link for the bak and sql files.

- Just create a new database and name it Northwind.
- Right click on your Northwind database and select New Query.
- Run the bak file, and that is all.

https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/71634